# CSS with border and margin issue

Tags: html, css

hello guys i'm trying to add some space between boxes in my list when resize the page, i'm new with css, help me :D

[image: Myproblem]

```css
nav{
  border: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
ul li
{
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    
}
nav ul li{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: auto;
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        <li>Shopping Cart</li>
        <li>Login</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Space where? You need to be more specific...you mean space left? Right? Above? Below? All around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
nav{
  border: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
ul li
{
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    display:inline-block;
}
nav ul li{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: auto;
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        <li>Shopping Cart</li>
        <li>Login</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

just add `display:block` to the li element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your inline elements, You can use the `line-height` property to create space between the rows. In this case, you don't need the `margin-bottom` rule.

```css
nav {
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 900;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  line-height: 20pt;
}
nav ul li {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: auto;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li>Shopping Cart</li>
    <li>Login</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Otherwise you can just set `display: inline-block;` to your list elements so that they behave like inline elements, where block properties can be applied to.

```css
nav {
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
ul li {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
nav ul li {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: auto;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li>Shopping Cart</li>
    <li>Login</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yes i dont like very much the first solution, the second works really well thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
nav{
  border: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
ul li
{
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    padding:5px 5px;
    margin-right:5px;
 
}
ul{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
  padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        <li>Shopping Cart</li>
        <li>Login</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```